# switchstatement triggers twice

Tags: iphone, xcode, switch-statement

can someone tell me why the switcstatement fires twice everytime I release the slider.

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

letters.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)[(UISlider *)sender value]];

}

- (IBAction) getValueSlider:(id )sender {

int n = [letters.text intValue];
switch (n) {    
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"%i",n);
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"%i",n);
        break;
    case 4:
        NSLog(@"%i",n);
        break;
    case 5:
        NSLog(@"%i",n);
        break;
    case 6:
        NSLog(@"%i",n);
        break;
    default:
        break;        
    }

}
```

its set for "touchUpInside" and "valuechange".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> its set for "touchUpInside" and "valuechange".

Your IBAction is firing on two events which will both happen when the slider value changes.

Comment: can you ellaborate...
why would touch up inside fire on valuechange...?

Comment: It won't, but it will fire once when you touchUpInside and once when the value changes.

Comment: not sure why it does this because there is after all a method for it.
if I do a lot of stuff in the event it happens twice and thats not good for speed in the application. And if I want to compare two values and alter one of them according to something...the second fireing wouldnt do what it is supposed to do because of an already changed value in the first eventhappening. very strange...

Comment: Why don't you get rid of the touchUpInside event? Do you care about anything other than a value change?